# Prove that if $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=-x^3+x^2+3x+2$ for $c∈(-1,2)$ the tangent line to f at $(c,f(c))$ is parallel to the tangent line of g at $(c,g(c))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Would have put this in the title but ran out of characters: The question also asks to find c, which is incidentally the thing I have most trouble with.

For the proof we know that by MVT: $$\frac{f(2)-f(-1)}{2-(-1)}=f'(c),\frac{g(2)-g(-1)}{2-(-1)}=g'(c)$$

When evaluating the functions at -1 and 2  we find that $f(-1)=g(-1)$ and $f(2)=g(2)$, thus $f'(c)=g'(c)$.

I'm not entirely sure about the validity of this proof, but I can't pinpoint why.

For finding c I'm stuck, and I think it's for some trivial reason, but I can't figure out why.

To find c I initially tried just solving the slope equation and got $f'(c)=1$ and $g'(c)=1$, good so far. But solving for 1 here gives different values of c, which makes me wonder about my proof. Then I decided to simply equate the derivatives:$$2x=-3x^2+2x+3 ⇒x=\sqrt{3}$$which also doesn't work! I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$2x=-3x^2+2x+3 ⇒x^2=1$$
Therefore $c=1$ makes the tangent line parallel and it is in the interval $(-1,2)$.

Comment: wow, I just realized my mistake. Algebra can be annoying sometimes